# How to take input in array in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to pass input into an array but it throws an error.

I already defined the value type in the array. I assigned the array with `'i'` and also passed the `int` type value.

```
>>> import array as arr
>>> a = arr.array('i', [int(input())])
print(a)
```

Here's the error that I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    a = arr.array('i', [int(input())])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'print(a)'
```

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and give more details about what you want: Give as uexample about the input and what you expect the result should look like.

Comment: Please post the full traceback you get when you try to run the code.

Answer (score 1):

You're typing this into a REPL environment, so each time you type a line, it runs (more or less), so when you enter the line:

```
a = arr.array('i', [int(input())])
```

The line after that is expecting the input for `input`, *not* the next line of code. Because you then type `print(a)` you're passing the value `"print(a)"` to `int`, essentially:

```
a = arr.array('i', [int("print(a)")])
```

Obviously `"print(a)"` is not a base 10 number so `int` is failing because `"p"` is not a character in base 10 (the digits 0 to 9 are the only valid digits).

To resolve this you need to pass a value for the `input` *before* continuing with your code:

```
>>> import array as arr
>>> a = arr.array('i', [int(input())])
5
>>> print(a)
array('i', [5])
```